# Error passing argument from pointer to non-enclosed address space

Tags: c, pointers, microcontroller, avr, mplab

I am using an ATMEGA16M1 microcontroller and the MPLAB IDE.

I have following function to write to the ports.

```
void Lcd8_Write_String(char *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
    Lcd8_Write_Char(a[i]);
}

void Lcd8_Write_Char(char a)
{
    pinChange(RS,1);             // => RS = 1
    Lcd8_Port(a);                //Data transfer
    pinChange(EN,1);             // => E = 1
    _delay_ms(1);
    pinChange(EN,0);             // => E = 04
    _delay_ms(1);
}
```

I call the function with `Lcd8_Write_String("Hello World");`.

I get:

> error: passing argument 1 of 'Lcd8_Write_String' from pointer to non-enclosed address space.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: maybe make a pointer to `const char`

Comment: @Mike aaaaand it compiled! Thank you very much. I've searched quite some time for an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write:

```
Lcd8_Write_String("Hello World");
```

The string `"Hello World"` will be in the Flash memory of your microcontroller and not in  the RAM. So you had to switch your function to:

```
void Lcd8_Write_String(const char *a)
```